# Unable to install arduino nodes in Node-Red

Tags: arduino, node-red

I have been trying to install arduino nodes in Node-Red through node-red-node-arduino following Node-Red's own guide (https://nodered.org/docs/hardware/arduino) to no avail. The node is marked as installed in the "Manage Palletes" tab, but it's disabled and refuses to enable itself. I tried to insert the sample code of the link above, but Node-Red doesn't recognize it. I installed the package arduino-firmata and node-red-node-serialport, and all the packages both locally (~/.node-red/node_modules) and globally (through -g option in npm), but the situation remains the same.

```
cd ~/.node-red
npm install node-red-node-arduino
npm install arduino-firmata
npm install node-red-node-serialport

sudo npm -g install node-red-node-arduino
sudo npm -g install arduino-firmata
sudo npm -g install node-red-node-serialport
```

They do spit out some weird logs, though, at least when installing locally.

```
> serialport@4.0.3 install /home/myusername/.node-red/node_modules/serialport
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

[serialport] Success: "/home/myusername/.node-red/node_modules/serialport/build/Release/serialport.node" is installed via remote
/home/myusername/.node-red
├── arduino-firmata@0.3.4 
├── node-red-node-arduino@0.0.9 
├── node-red-node-serialport@0.4.0 
└── serialport@4.0.3 

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/myusername/.node-red/package.json'
npm WARN .node-red No description
npm WARN .node-red No repository field.
npm WARN .node-red No README data
npm WARN .node-red No license field.
npm WARN In serialport@4.0.3 replacing bundled version of minimist with minimist@0.0.8
npm WARN In serialport@4.0.3 replacing bundled version of abbrev with abbrev@1.0.9
npm WARN In serialport@4.0.3 replacing bundled version of delegates with delegates@1.0.0
...
```

Here is the log that shows up when running node-red in the terminal.

```
[warn] [arduino] Error: Cannot find module 'firmata/node_modules/serialport'
```

Comment: The WARN messages while installing can be ignored as they are warnings not errors. I see you have "..." at the end, is there more you have missed out?

Comment: Actually given you now probably have the packages installed in at least 2 different places which may clash, it may be better if you post to the mailing list where we can more easily guide you through some steps. The mailing list is here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/node-red

Comment: @hardillb there are about 20 more lines similar to the last three: serialport@4.0.3 replacing bundled version of X with X@version. And thanks, will be posting there